# Cant find the exact fuel pump i need for my 04 mercury mountaineer please help

Tags: mercury, fuel-pump

04 mercury mountaineer needs fuel pump and im having trouble finding the one with my exact connector. I keep getting one with 3 holes in the connector and I need 4 holes

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the wires and then use the connector from the old one and put the wires from the new on in the correct places.

Make sure you check to make sure which is live etc.

Comment: Agreed. From what I'm seeing, it states, "To replace a 1st design part with 1x4 connector customer may need To remove the jumper harness on the vehicle To install". I'm not exactly sure how that'd work, however, the newer style pump should work just fine, the need to change out the connector from new to old is what has to happen.